# WebAPI/MVC - sending json list to server

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem sending 2 particular objects to the server.

1. I have a form with an input and a text area

   Send

   function SendServer()
   { 
    $.ajax({

   ```
               url: '/api/Service',
               type: "POST",
               contentType: 'application/json',
               data: {} //!!!
               success: function (response) {
               },

               error: function (er) {
               }
           });
   ```

   }

the issue is that my text area will contain an user input json of the form:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "john smith",
      "lastaccess": "2016-01-01T07:21:31 -00:00"
    },
    {
      "name": "paul marley",
      "lastaccess": "2016-01-01T07:22:31 -00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to send both values to the server:

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
  public string Post( *something* )
  {}
}
```

I can reach the server, but I donno how to properly send the 2 objects so I can retrieve them on the server?

I have been trying a lot of options, nothing worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending a json which user enters using a form, you might consider using `JObject` class as your web api method parameter.

So in your form

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" id="val1" name="val1" value="1" />
    <textarea class="form-control" id="json" name="json"></textarea>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Now, on the button click,read the values of both the inputs and create a new object, and send that to the server.

```
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var v = $("#val1").val();
        var t = $("#json").val();
        var d = { val1: v, json: t };
        $.ajax({

            url: '/api/values',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },

            error: function (er) {
                console.log(er);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

And in the WebApi endpoint, you may use JObject as the parameter. The default model binder will be able to map the posted values to an object of JObject.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JObject value)
    {
        var v = value["val1"];
        var j = value["json"];
        // do something with these 
        // v.Value will give you the value
        return Request.CreateResponse("Something received");
    }
```

JObject class belongs to  `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace. So make sure to have a using statement to include that in your web api controller.

Comment: yes, this is what I was going around in circles to find, thank you!!